# Do all heroes eventually progress their abilities to have an alternative effect?

Tags: heroes

Throughout the series, many of the heroes (but not all shown to) slowly progress their abilities to have an alternative effect.

e.g. The Haitian, can remove memories and also secondary block other heroes from using their abililties. Claire can regenerate tissue and then later on can regenerate entire limbs. Matt Parkman can read thoughts and then later implant thoughts.

Do all heroes eventually gain an alternative ability of their main ability?

Comment: I'd disagree that these are *alternative* powers and more that what you're considering their "main" power is really just a less understood or under-utilized version. The Haitian, for example, can manipulate the brain. Syler shows that powers are controlled by the brain. So The Haitian could use the same power to block memories of events or block the brain from being able to use them. Similarly "telepathy" traditionally works both ways. Parkman originally just knew how to read minds before being able to push thoughts.

Comment: I would like to add that only the Haitian has "two powers" originally. Parkman only "gains" an ability when the talentless writers run out of plot.

Comment: @phantom42 Claire's ability does, however, get stronger many times as the series progresses, eventually reaching the point where her nerve endings regenerate faster than they can register pain.  (And note that Adam reached that point and (I think) told her about it before it happened)

Comment: @phantom42 - might be choice of words, however you want to look at it, there are two effects of their powers. And that is what the question is asking.

Comment: I've just reworded the question as I feel it was making people assume I meant do people have "two" powers, what I'm really after is do all heroes have abiilties that progress to have two effects, for which the best example is Matt Parkman; read thoughts, and later implant thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Except for the Haitian, no.

Long answer:
I'd have to agree with phantom42 that some Heroes' characters have multi-faceted abilities (abilities that can be used in more than one way/have more than one effect), but only the Haitian (& Peter, Arthur and Sylar, who don't count since they can acquire abilities) have more than one ability.

Claire's ability is re-generation, while this starts out as tissue regeneration, Adam Monroe tells her that the more they use their regeneration ability, the more powerful it becomes, until they're effectively immortal.

Matt's "push" ability is a refinement of his mind-control (telepathy) ability, that he discovers as he explores his ability and learns how to control and use it. His father had the same (multi-effect) ability.

Tracey Strauss is another interesting example:
Originally her ability seemed to be to freeze things, then, to save Rebel, she freezes herself and everything around her. After she melts and turns to water, she eventually "pulls herself together", learning how to switch between human and water forms. So her ability should probably be described as water manipulation.

The Haitian is the only character who genuinely seems to have more than one ability, although both abilities are brain-related, there're so different that this seems a bit of a stretch to me (why can't he pull/push thoughts like Matt if this is the case?).

Answer (score 0):

old thread, but gonna comment anyway :P

The Haitian's case, from my understanding, is no exception. His ability is to disrupt brain activity. It renders powers useless (because powers are activated by the brain), he can make people pass out (by disrupting their normal brain function) and by extension, he can make memories disappear (disrupting more permanently the memory fonction of the brain (which seems to have a side effect if used repetedly, like for Noah's wife).

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: This does not answer the question of whether or not all EVOs can gain secondary abilities.